# Pygame using time.sleep to wait for x seconds not executing code above it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to recreate Pong in pygame and have tried to change the color of the net to red or green, based on who scores. I am able to keep it red or green after someone scores, until a different person scores, however, I want to change the net color back to black after 3 seconds. I tried using time.sleep(3) but whenever I did it, the net will stay as black. `

```
  elif pong.hitedge_right:     
       game_net.color = (255,0,0)     
       time.sleep(3)       
       scoreboard.sc1 +=1
       print(scoreboard.sc1)
       pong.centerx = int(screensize[0] * 0.5)
       pong.centery = int(screensize[1] * 0.5)

       scoreboard.text = scoreboard.font.render('{0}      {1}'.formatscoreboard.sc1,scoreboard.sc2), True, (255, 255, 255))

       pong.direction = [random.choice(directions),random.choice(directions2)]
       pong.speedx = 2
       pong.speedy = 3

       pong.hitedge_right = False
       running+=1
       game_net.color=(0,0,0)
```

Ideally, it should turn red for 3 seconds, then update the scoreboard and restart the ball, however, instead, the entire thing pauses and it skips straight to changing the net color to black. I believe there is a better way of doing this, or maybe I am using time.sleep totally wrong, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a minimal working example instead of a fragment? At first glance your code looks right to me.

Comment: you can't use `time.sleep()` because it stops mainloop which do everthing in prorgam. mainloop has to run and you have to check current time and execute this part after 3 seconds. You can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get current time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `sleep()` in PyGame (or any GUI framework) because it stops `mainloop` which updates other elements.

You have to remember current time in variable and later in loop compare it with current time to see if 3 seconds left. Or you have to create own EVENT which will be fired after 3 second - and you have to check this event in `for event`.

It may need more changes in code so I can show only how it can look like

---

Using time/ticks

```
# create before mainloop with default value 
update_later = None


elif pong.hitedge_right:     
   game_net.color = (255,0,0)     
   update_later = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000 # 3000ms = 3s


# somewhere in loop
if update_later is not None and pygame.time.get_ticks() >= update_later:
   # turn it off
   update_later = None

   scoreboard.sc1 +=1
   print(scoreboard.sc1)
   # ... rest ...
```

---

Using events

```
# create before mainloop with default value 
UPDATE_LATER = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

elif pong.hitedge_right:     
   game_net.color = (255,0,0)     
   pygame.time.set_timer(UPDATE_LATER, 3000) # 3000ms = 3s

# inside `for `event` loop
if event.type == UPDATE_LATER:
   # turn it off
   pygame.time.set_timer(UPDATE_LATER, 0)

   scoreboard.sc1 +=1
   print(scoreboard.sc1)
   # ... rest ...
```

Comment: BTW: see examples [time-execute-function](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/time-execute-function) and [clock](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/clock)